# Group by query in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables

**Table 1 :**

```
id | user_id  | pattern
1  |   3      | ^1212.*
2  |   3      | ^192.*
3  |   4      | ^20.*
```

**Table 2 :**

```
id |pattern | start_date          | comment
1  |^1212.* | 2014-03-22 20:10:13 | India-Gujarat
2  |^1212.* | 2014-03-24 20:10:13 | India -Maharastra
3  |^1212.* | 2014-03-25 20:10:13 | India -uttar pradesh
4  |^1212.* | 2014-03-27 20:10:13 | India -Madhya pradesh
5  |^1212.* | 2014-03-29 20:10:13 | India -Rajasthan
6  |^192.* | 2014-03-22 20:10:13  | Africa
7  |^20.* | 2014-03-22 20:10:13   | Indonesia- first
8  |^20.* | 2014-03-26 20:10:13   | indonesia -second
9  |^1212.* | 2014-03-22 20:10:13 | India- kerala
10 |^13.* | 2014-03-22 20:10:13   | Usa
11 |^13.* | 2014-03-22 20:12:13   | usa
12 |^14.* | 2014-03-22 20:10:13   | U.k
```

**Required Output :**

```
id | pattern | start_date
8  |^20.* | 2014-03-26 20:10:13 | Indonesia-first
10 | ^13.*  | 2014-03-22 20:12:13 | USA
12 | ^14.*  | 2014-03-22 20:10:13 | U.k
```

**Output Requirement :**

1. Pattern doesn't exist in table 1 based on  user_id={current user}
   here we can see user_id have 1212,92,20 but its doesn;t have 20,13,14 pattern in table 1
2. Pattern which is show from table 2 with its comment as well start_date must be most closest than current time
3. pattern must be distinct

i have tried using php code using 3 times execute query and its take long time

1. select distinct(pattern)from table2 group by pattern
2. select * from table1 where user_id = login_id
3. foreach loop in php (select * from table2 where id not in (output of query2) and pattern like ('123'))

so is it possible using single query in postgresql

Comment: I barely understand anything. Please describe your problem in more detail. You want all rows of table 2, whose pattern does not exist in the part of table 1 where `user_id` = current user?

Comment: @GhostGambler yes exactly

Comment: Then: why is there only one `^13.*` pattern in the required output ?

Comment: @joop nope required patterns are 20,13,14 which is not appeared in table 1 for user_id =13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.pattern
FROM table2 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 b ON a.pattern = b.pattern AND b.user_id = {current_user}
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

You join all rows from table 2 with all the rows from table 1, based on their pattern and only if it belongs to the current user. Then you select only those from a, which could not be joined.

### Update

Based on your comment, again I am not 100% sure what you mean. One way would be adding `DISTINCT` to the query above.

Another variant would be

```
SELECT DISTINCT pattern FROM table2
EXCEPT
SELECT pattern FROM table1 WHERE user_id = {current user}
```

### Update 2

Based on the information that you want the additional information from the most recent row of table 2, this query might help you:

```
SELECT a.* FROM table2 a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT pattern, MAX(start_date) AS max_start_date
  FROM table2
  GROUP BY pattern
) mostrecent
ON a.pattern = mostrecent.pattern AND a.start_date = mostrecent.max_start_date
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 b ON a.pattern = b.pattern AND b.user_id = {current_user}
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

The upper part requests all most-recent rows from table2. The lower part (beginning with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`) joins this to table 1 and (as before) selects only those rows, which have no row in table1.

Another solution which works specifically in Postgresql 8.4+ would be

```
WITH mostrecent AS (
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pattern ORDER BY start_date DESC) AS rank
  FROM table2
)
SELECT a.*
FROM mostrecent a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 b ON a.pattern = b.pattern AND b.user_id = {current_user}
WHERE b.id IS NULL AND a.rank = 1
```

Comment: Thanks its really work fine.but if  more than 1 records of same patterns are available in table 2 than its show all records  of same pattern but i want only distinct pattern of table 2

Comment: I've changed the first solution and added another one, which returns a slightly different result, in my original answer.

Comment: Really Thanks for your reply but as u said its now show only distinct pattern now but i want distinct pattern as well as full detail of that pattern so is it possible?

Comment: This is not possible without further specification. If you only want distinct patterns from table 2, that is ok, but if you want also the other columns, you must tell from which of the rows the additional data should come from. At the moment the only additional data is `start_date`, so should always be the most recent `start_date` be returned?

Comment: Nope i have also some additonal fields but all of that are available only in table2 like comment (text) which is not mention in question but i want also select comment as well as start_date that's it nothing else

Comment: but, which one? If you have the same pattern, with multiple start-dates and you only want to retrieve one row, which start-date should be returned?

Comment: yes only single start_date with its comment need to be return

Comment: Sorry, but this does not make sense. I barely understand you and you do not seem to understand my questions. Sorry, but I cannot help this way.

Comment: First of all thanks for Helping me  but i am Sorry for my bed English but after edited question i hope you will get me what i need exactly output

Comment: Ok, see my edit above. I inserted two possible solutions, which should help you.