# postgresql query based on condition

Tags: postgresql

I have single table.

**Example :**

---

```
id | pattern | currencyid|pricelist_id| comment|cost|start_date
1  | ^.123.* |         30|           2| USA    |2.00|2014-03-20 20:12:00
2  | ^.123.* |         30|           2| USA    |3.00|2014-03-22 20:12:00
3  | ^.123.* |         30|           2| KENYA  |1.00|2014-03-24 20:12:00
4  | ^.123.* |         22|           2| CANADA |4.00|2014-03-26 20:12:00
5  | ^.123.* |         22|           2| CANADA |5.00|2014-03-29 20:12:00
6  | ^.123.* |         30|           2| USA    |6.00|2014-03-30 20:12:00
7  | ^.123.* |         30|           2| USA    |6.00|2014-04-12 20:12:00
8  | ^.123.* |         22|           2| INDIA  |8.00|2014-04-12 20:12:00
```

---

**Required OutPut :**

```
id | pattern | currencyid|pricelist_id| comment|old_cost|old_start_date     |NEW_COST|NEW_start_date
3  | ^.123.* |         30|           2| KENYA  |1.00    |2014-03-24 20:12:00|6.00    |2014-03-30 20:12:00
4  | ^.123.* |         22|           2| CANADA |4.00    |2014-03-26 20:12:00|8.00    |2014-04-12 20:12:00
```

**Description :**

Here first of all Patterns are always may be same or may be different.

1. start_date > NOW() AND most closest to current datetime then it would be consider as a new_start_Date and its cost called as a new_cost
2. start_date < NOW() AND most closest to current datetime then it would be consider as a old_date and its cost as a old_cost
3. add some other where conditions.

**STEPS :**

I am getting required result using below queries which is very long process.
If i have some additional where then its only added only in below query which is not appropriate its need to be added in all below queries and give me result based on that

```
SELECT pattern, pricelist_id, currency_id
FROM "table"
WHERE pricelist_id=2
GROUP BY "pattern", "pricelist_id", "currency_id";

OUTPUT:
pattern | pricelist_id|currencyid
 ^.123.*|            2|30
 ^.123.*|            2|22
```

**Using foreach loop in php execute below queries**

```
SELECT "id" as new_id, "cost" as new_cost, "start_date" as new_start_date
FROM "table" 
WHERE "pricelist_id" = '2' 
  AND "start_date" > '2014-03-28 10:35:26' 
  AND "pattern" = '^.123.*' 
  AND "currencyid" = '30' 
ORDER BY "start_date" ASC
LIMIT 1

SELECT "id" as old_id, "cost" as old_cost, "start_date" as old_date, "comment"
FROM "table" 
WHERE "pricelist_id" = '2' 
  AND "start_date" <= '2014-03-28 10:35:26' 
  AND "pattern" = '^123.*' 
  AND "currencyid" = '30' 
ORDER BY "id" desc, "start_date" DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

But its take a long time for 1 million records so if possible then please suggest me query which runs smoothly.

Is it possible to fulfill all above requirements by single PostgreSQL query ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Group by query in postgresql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22686771/group-by-query-in-postgresql)

Comment: Both are different Things

Comment: Try to describe the logic behind getting your expected result, if you can. How would you do it, step by step, if you had to do it by hand?

Comment: @CraigRinger I describe my logic to getting required result.Please just look at it and if you have some suggestions then please let me know.

Comment: Where do the inputs for the loop queries come from? For example, where did the start_date of `2014-03-28 10:35:26` come from? Is that meant to be the current timestamp in your queries?

Comment: Thanks for reply Yes exactly start_date" > '2014-03-28 10:35:26' coming from current timestamp

Comment: That's a tricky one! Don't have time to really work on it, and this is the closest I came with a quick look. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e25fa/24

Comment: Yeah i have tried u little bit closer. But is it possible to make more simple or without using subqueries because subqueries always taking time.if possible then please make query smoothly also

Answer (score 0):

Try to use WITH construction to obtain calculated data:

```
with max_date as(select * from table where start_date < now() order by start_date desc limit 1),
min_date as(select * from table where start_date > now() order by start_date asc limit 1)
SELECT code, begin_time, (select code from max_date), (select code from min_date)
FROM table v 
where id in (
    (select id from max_date)
    union all
    (select id from min_date)
)
```